# Не включается статическое кэширование на nginx

Tags: nginx, modx

Нужно настроить кэширование на сайте. Используем cms MODX.
Вставила внутри server:

```
set $webroot '/var/www/L06';
root $webroot;


location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|swf|tiff|swf|flv)$ {
root $webroot;
expires 2M;
add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

По статистике pagespeed - не заработало. 
Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, как поступить.

Comment: Покажите весь конфиг, если там ничего секретного.

Comment: Большое спасибо за готовность помочь! Нужные настройки были просто не в том конфиге! Спасибо!